# how to display full resolation camera roll images in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have try to display full resolution camera roll image in windows phone but not solve ,here i have use Stretch="None" property in xaml but it show image in small grid box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this goal via simply add image tag in grid without setting any height or width

```
<Grid>
    <Image>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i have use same  <grid > tag but not find solution

Comment: @user3024175 screenshot?

Comment: screen shot of xaml<Grid ><phone:Pivot Items Source="{Binding}"><phone:Pivot. Item Template><Data Template><Image   Name="images"Stretch="Fill"Source="{Binding}"/></Grid>

Comment: @user3024175 remove stretch  atribute

Comment: I have already try to use "stretch" property remove also use all these property methods,eg.fill,none etc but not work

Comment: @user3024175 so you want that if image is bigger it should be seen bigger although it don't seen properly

Comment: all images display same size,but I have need to display camera roll images like user select camera roll images and swipe images one by one and it display full resolution image, i.s if image captured full size(image captured vertically then these images size has larger than images captured horizontally).I have to display images different size like vertically & horizontally depending to camera captured images.

Comment: all images display same size,but I have need to display camera roll images like user select camera roll images and swipe images one by one and it display full resolution image, i.s if image captured full size(image captured vertically then these images size has larger than images captured horizontally).I have to display images different size like vertically & horizontally depending to camera captured images.

Comment: @user3024175 are you testing in emulator?

Comment: I have testing in windows phone development device.

Comment: this is my xamlfile<grid> <phone:Pivot  x:Name="listbox"ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1"><phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><image Name="image1"Source="{Binding}">

Comment: i want to display full resolution image but display top most area of every image has blank,(header of every image)

Comment: in image tag use height and width auto

Comment: height&width doesn't work.Then i have set pivot margin="0,-100,0,0" property set and i have get full resolution image

Comment: @Siddhu I don't think this is solution

Comment: also i have delete  Stretch="" property in image tag&set DecodePixelWidth = 550; for image .Its work fine like picture library swipe images size..also i have use <Grid> tag include all other tag<pivot>,<image>etc.Thanks for giving trick to <grid>tag.